# How to list all featured questions with favourite tags?

Tags: support, search, bounties, tag-watching, bountied-tab

I'd like to view all bounty questions tagged with my favorite tags. How can I do that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no option to browse questions tagged with your favorite tags directly. But you can browse questions with `/tagged` page.
E.g.
[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql)

Here you can add multiple tags for filter using `+or+`.
E.g.
[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+or+mysql`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+or+mysql)

Now you can switch to the featured tab using `sort=featured` in the parameter.
E.g.
[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+or+mysql?sort=featured`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql+or+mysql?sort=featured)

Note: You can also use wildcards here.
E.g.
[`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sql*?sort=featured`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/*sql*?sort=featured)

Comment: You can search for questions tagged with your favourite tags by searching for "intags:mine", i.e.

http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=intags%3Amine

Comment: @rogersillito - Nice. Thanks to inform me. But there is no option in [Advanced search](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/searching) to search featured questions. So we can't apply `intags:mine` here. :(

Comment: what if the tag contains `+` like [tag:c++]? How do we escape the `+` sign?

Comment: @phuclv: You can do that by searching directly from the search box e.g. [`[sql] or [c++]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sql%20or%20c%2b%2b)