# Any plans for the feature "Listing questions with favourite tags (newest/popular/unanswered/etc)"

Tags: feature-request, tag-watching

Me (and I assume many users) prefer to browse all their favourite tags separately from tags unrelated to their skills or interests. As far as I know there is no link to only list favourite tags (as you can with a particular tag).

The answer here ([How to list all featured questions with favourite tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181918/how-to-list-all-featured-questions-with-favourite-tags)) shows how to "hack it", but that is not very dynamic or user friendly (even if saving as a bookmark this is static to my favourites at the point of bookmarking)

Is there a reason why S.O is lacking the "show-questions-with-my-favourite-tag"-feature? Are there or have there been discussions for introducing it?

Comment: I just found that there is a popular question regarding this (asked 3 years ago, active 1 year ago), but that unfortunately has had its status declined (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11563/tab-for-questions-that-are-labeled-with-favorite-tags)

Answer (score 1):

There is no hard-and-fast rule regarding which features get implemented and which don't. However, a highly-upvoted feature request certainly gets more attention than one which doesn't garner many votes.

The linked request got two upvotes and one downvote, which probably indicates that the feature isn't worth the developers' time. For best results, upvote the question and consider adding an answer there that convinces people to see your side of the issue.